# Spring MVC 4 configuration not finding my controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to Spring MVC 4 I am trying to do the java configuration setup but it seems Spring is not finding my Controller it is running fine no errors on startup I can even explicitly call a jsp but if I try to call my controller it does nothing

e.g.
`localhost:8080/apollo/hello.jsp` <-- this renders fine if I put my JSP in the webapp directory

What I want is to call my login.jsp using my controller

My project structure is

```
com
  +apollo
  -WebAppInitializer.java
  -WebConfig.java
src
 +main
   +webapp
   -**hello.jsp**
     +WEB-INF
       +view
       -**login.jsp**
```

here is my Configuration

```
package com.apollo;    
import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.apollo")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }       

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        /*registry.addResourceHandler("/pdfs/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pdf/");
          registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/");*/
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

Here is my Initializer Class

```
package com.apollo;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();            
        context.register(WebConfig.class);
        return context;
    }

}
```

here is my Controller

```
package com.apollo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String greeting  (Model model){
        System.out.println("controller???");
        model.addAttribute("greeting" , "Hello World");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **basePackages** mean the **package** contains the **controller**

Here is the problem:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.apollo")
```

You should change to

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.apollo.controller")
```

If you put controller to modules, you should scan like this

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.apollo.**.controller")
```